# Curl Options in Bash

Tags: php, bash

How to set the following things for Curl in Bash?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Comment: I believe those are the default options for `curl` in bash. `-I` would be for just the headers.

Comment: -I? How is it used?

Comment: See [man curl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like that?

```
curl -s https://stackoverflow.com
```

**explanation**

```
-s      # silent, disable progress meter
```